# Unable to insert all the data into the database using rxJava2

Tags: android, rx-java2

I am facing the issue while inserting the data into the local database .
i have the following scenerio . when there is the data in the local database then fetch the data from the local database ,if no data is present then make an API call then insert that object into the local storage.

Note : i am getting the data from the API as a list . I have tried like this but only able to insert one data to the local database

```
  @Override
        public void getEventDetail(JSONObject jsonObject) {
            Single<List<EventDetailResponse>> getAllEventFromLocalDb = getDataManager().getAllEventDetail();
            Single<List<EventDetailResponse>> getEventFromNetwork = getDataManager().doEventDetailCall(jsonObject);
            Flowable<List<EventDetailResponse>> response = Single.concat(getAllEventFromLocalDb, getEventFromNetwork);
            FlattenTransform<EventDetailResponse> flattenList = new FlattenTransform<EventDetailResponse>();

                   getCompositeDisposable().add(
                     (response)
                    .filter(list -> !list.isEmpty())
                    .first(new ArrayList<>())
                    .map(list->{
                        if(!list.isEmpty()){
                            for (int i=0;i<list.size();i++){
                                insertEventIntoLocalStorage(list.get(i));
                            }
                        }
                        return  list;
                    })
                    .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                    .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                    .subscribe(s->{

                    }));
        }

public void insertEventIntoLocalStorage(EventDetailResponse eventDetailResponse) {
        getCompositeDisposable().add(getDataManager()
                .insertEventDetail(eventDetailResponse)
                .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                .subscribe(aLong -> {
                    Log.e("data","data inserted");
                }, throwable -> {
                    handleError(throwable);
                }));
    }
```

I have got the logic  !! Hope it's help someone : I am editing the above code below . Any good answer more than this appreciated

Post Request to Server to find the data :

```
@Override
    public void getEventDetail(JSONObject jsonObject) {
               getCompositeDisposable().add(
                 (getDataManager().doEventDetailCall(jsonObject))
                .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                .subscribe(list->{
                    if(!list.isEmpty()){
                        insertEventIntoLocalStorage(list);
                    }

                }));
    }
```

Insert the data to database when we receive the response from the network :

```
public void insertEventIntoLocalStorage(List<EventDetailResponse> eventDetailResponse) {
        getCompositeDisposable().add(getDataManager()
                .insertEventDetail(eventDetailResponse)
                .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                .subscribe(aLong -> {
                    loadDataFromDb();
                }, throwable -> {
                    handleError(throwable);
                }));
    }
```

Finally load the Data from database

```
@Override
    public void loadDataFromDb() {
        getMvpView().showLoading();
        getCompositeDisposable().add(getDataManager()
                .getAllEventDetail()
                .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                .subscribe(result->{
                    getMvpView().showEventDetailFromDb(result);
                    getMvpView().hideLoading();
                },throwable -> {
                    handleError(throwable);
                    getMvpView().hideLoading();
                }));
    }
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in the stacktrace? Why are you trying to insert data inside the `map` operator?

Comment: @piotr.wittchen No there is no error "data inserted " log getting called one time only but my list size is two . Can you let me know then where to call insertEventIntoLocalStorage . if i am calling from the subscribe of getEventDetail(..) method , i am getting the same issue

Comment: @piotr.wittchen any idea , i am stucked with it from 48 hrs :(

Comment: I'm a bit confused with this question. There's a lot of code and error could be anywhere, so it's hard to give you a concrete answer. Maybe try to debug this code or simplify it.

Comment: @piotr.wittchen the issue is resolved from my side and i had given the answer above also , but i have one query that , can i call second observable from 1st onsubscribe method ? i had done like this only,dunno it's proper way to do it or not .